# Magento 1.9.2 - Wrong products pictures names

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have an issue. Product picture not displaying in transactional email. When i try to put picture path in browser adress field i am getting 500 Internal Server Error. Media folder and all sub folders and files has 777 permission. **The issue is cached pictures has wrong names**...they have spaces and other "bad" symbols. For example:

`/media/catalog/product/cache/.../14-9902063710001+(1).jpg`

but this picture working correct:

`/media/catalog/product/cache/.../1.jpg`

How to fix pictures names issue ?

Comment: clear all cache, and regenerate cache piktures, after reindex all catalog.

Comment: hi, thank's for answer ! Unfortunately its not helping. Picture still not available in transactional email and if i try to open picture via browser adress text field.

Comment: sorry I don't read transaction email, you can show you email template, or say what is module used for paste pictures to you email. email template you can finde in `system -> configuration -> transaction emails` and find you order email remember template name. And go to `system -> transaction emails` and click in grid you template. If grid is empty click `add new` after click button `load template`, after loading you can copy text mail template and paste here. p.s. sorry for my English.